# Inherit Sales Dashboard to add some functionality (Odoo 10)

Tags: xml, odoo

Hello I am trying to inherit Sales Dashboard view in order to add something that will link to my One2many records. I tried to  inherit view but gets error.

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sales_targets_kanban_inherit_id" >
            <field name="name">Sales Target Kanban Inherit</field>
            <field name="model">sales.target</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sales_team.crm_team_salesteams_view_kanban"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <kanban>
                 </kanban>
            </field>
    </record>
```

I am getting following error:

```
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `color` does not exist
Error context:
View `Sales Target Kanban Inherit`
[view_id: 1870, xml_id: n/a, model: sales.target, parent_id: 682]
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sales_targets_kanban_inherit_id">
        <field name="name">Sales Target Kanban Inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sales.target</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sales_team.crm_team_salesteams_view_kanban"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <kanban>
             </kanban>
        </field>
</record>
```

Hopes for suggestion

Comment: The msg error is pretty clear, The field 'color' does not exist in this inherit view, with this model

Comment: So change the `model` tag from `sales.target` to `crm.team`

Comment: but my model name is sales.target and its a custom model with no color field

Comment: But you inherit a view from `crm.team` not `sales.target`, and this the source of problem

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code like this:

```
<record id="crm_team_salesteams_view_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.team.kanban</field>
        <field name="model">crm.team</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sales_team.crm_team_salesteams_view_kanban"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//templates" position="before">
                <field name="your_field"/>

            </xpath

          <xpath expr="//div[contains(@class, 'o_kanban_primary_right')]" 
           position="inside">
              <!-- .............. -->
         </xpath>
          </data>
          </field>
```

Comment: I want to create kanban view in this dashboard. But I will have to use my model to access my fields thats why I put "sales.target", if I try with this module gets updated. No error but nothing changes in the dashboard.